# Unable to access contents of returned mongodb/mongoose object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to retrieve values from "UserKid" collection where "fname" and "Parent_id" are used as conditions. It returns "contentLinkIds" in "det1". I've checked by printing it on the console that it is returning the required content. However, I am not able to access the key-value pairs within the returned object.

```
UserKid.find({Parent_id:ObjectId(det._id).toString(),fname:fname},'contentLinkIDs', function(err1, det1){
 console.log("Det1:" + det1);
 console.log("DET1 id:"+ det1._id);
 console.log("contentLinkIDs: "+det1.contentLinkIDs);
/*some code here*/
});
```

Output on console:

```
 Det1:{ _id: 58e08c96f36d2878e036cf21,
 contentLinkIDs: [ '58e2dea6f36d283c9c86dd14' ] }
 DET1 id:undefined
 contentLinkIDs: undefined
```

Whats going wrong here?

Additonal info: I am using mongoose in Node.js/Express to connect to mlab.

Comment: first, I assume that, _id is mongoldb index, so before you print it, you have to convert it to string with .toString(), second contentLinkIDs is array, so you have to print it with a loop, or make it .toString(), or .join(), to convert it to string format

Comment: Figured it out! When I use "find", the object returned seems to be an array of objects. So det1[0]._id and so on can access the content instead.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who gets these errors, When I use "find", the object returned seems to be an array of objects. So det1[0]._id and so on can access the content instead.